# Model validation using StringLength not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

In Visual Studio 2022, I created an ASP.NET Core Razor page application and found model string validation using `StringLength` attribute didn't display error messages when a text string was over the defined maximum limit, and just allows to enter maximum size on content view. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class Student
{
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} length must be between {2} and {1}.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

<form method="post">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="right">
            <label asp-for="Students.Name"></label> :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Students.Name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Students.tName" class="message"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to change   `<span asp-validation-for="Students.tName" class="message"></span>`  to `asp-validation-for="Students.Name"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like below:

```
<form method="post">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="right">
                <label asp-for="Students.Name"></label> :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" asp-for="Students.Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Students.Name" class="message"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

> using StringLength attribute didn't display error messages when a text
> string was over the defined maximum limit, and just allows to enter
> maximum size on content view.

Client-side validation prevents submission until the form is valid.So we need to add script references to support client-side validation.

> it doesn't not allow you to enter more than 20 characters, no meesage
> pops up to notify the user

MaximumLength Property and asp-for specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the  element, so it doesn't not allow us to enter more than 20 characters, then we don't exceed 20, no meesage
pops up .

If you want exceed 20, and meesage
pops up, we can hide the input with asp-for , and create another input to  display max error, then use jquery to set the value to the hidden name field.

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Students.Name" class="control-label"></label>
       
         <input asp-for="Students.Name" class="form-control"  type="hidden"/>
         <input name="Students.Name"  id="name"  class="form-control" />
       
        <span asp-validation-for="Students.Name" class="text-danger"></span>

    </div>
    <button id="button" type="submit" >Save</button>
    </form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

           <script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var nameval = $("#name").val();
        $("#Students_Name").val(nameval);
    })
           </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I tried to add these three jQuery reference in _layout.cshtml.  Now I set the length between 2 to 20, ff you enter one character, yes the error message pops up but it doesn't not allow you to enter more than 20 characters, no meesage pops up to notify the user.

Comment: @zbx888   [MaximumLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.maximumlength?view=net-7.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-stringlengthattribute-maximumlength) Property  and `asp-for` specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the `<input>` element, that's why "it doesn't not allow you to enter more than 20 characters, no meesage pops up to notify the user.". My update give you an option , you can refer to it.

Comment: Hi @zbx888, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?